# In graphX, how to partition a graph with a custom PartitionStrategy that makes use of its topology?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I want to add a new PartitionStrategy making use of graph topology information. Still, I find the PartitionStrategy only has a function as follows. I can not find any functions that can receive graph data.

```scala
  override def getPartition(src: VertexId, dst: VertexId, numParts: PartitionID): PartitionID = {
    println("partitioning!")
    numParts
  }
```

,this function only can get one peice of src-dst information.

In spark graphx source `org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.GraphImpl`, I find the code as follow,

```scala
  override def partitionBy(
      partitionStrategy: PartitionStrategy, numPartitions: Int): Graph[VD, ED] = {
    val edTag = classTag[ED]
    val vdTag = classTag[VD]
    val newEdges = edges.withPartitionsRDD(edges.map { e =>
      val part: PartitionID = partitionStrategy.getPartition(e.srcId, e.dstId, numPartitions)
      (part, (e.srcId, e.dstId, e.attr))
    }
      .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(numPartitions))
      .mapPartitionsWithIndex(
        { (pid: Int, iter: Iterator[(PartitionID, (VertexId, VertexId, ED))]) =>
          val builder = new EdgePartitionBuilder[ED, VD]()(edTag, vdTag)
          iter.foreach { message =>
            val data = message._2
            builder.add(data._1, data._2, data._3)
          }
          val edgePartition = builder.toEdgePartition
          Iterator((pid, edgePartition))
        }, preservesPartitioning = true)).cache()
    GraphImpl.fromExistingRDDs(vertices.withEdges(newEdges), newEdges)
  }
```

,the `.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(numPartitions))` is as follow, `partitionBy` is from `PairRDDFunctions` class as follow,

```scala
  /**
   * Return a copy of the RDD partitioned using the specified partitioner.
   */
  def partitionBy(partitioner: Partitioner): RDD[(K, V)] = self.withScope {
    if (keyClass.isArray && partitioner.isInstanceOf[HashPartitioner]) {
      throw new SparkException("HashPartitioner cannot partition array keys.")
    }
    if (self.partitioner == Some(partitioner)) {
      self
    } else {
      new ShuffledRDD[K, V, V](self, partitioner)
    }
  }
```

the `HashPartitioner` is as follow,

```scala
/**
 * A [[org.apache.spark.Partitioner]] that implements hash-based partitioning using
 * Java's `Object.hashCode`.
 *
 * Java arrays have hashCodes that are based on the arrays' identities rather than their contents,
 * so attempting to partition an RDD[Array[_]] or RDD[(Array[_], _)] using a HashPartitioner will
 * produce an unexpected or incorrect result.
 */
class HashPartitioner(partitions: Int) extends Partitioner {
  require(partitions >= 0, s"Number of partitions ($partitions) cannot be negative.")

  def numPartitions: Int = partitions

  def getPartition(key: Any): Int = key match {
    case null => 0
    case _ => Utils.nonNegativeMod(key.hashCode, numPartitions)
  }

  override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
    case h: HashPartitioner =>
      h.numPartitions == numPartitions
    case _ =>
      false
  }

  override def hashCode: Int = numPartitions
}
```

,but these functions can not get graph data.

I read the PowerGraph [distributed_constrained_random_ingress.hpp](https://github.com/jegonzal/PowerGraph/blob/master/src/graphlab/graph/ingress/distributed_constrained_random_ingress.hpp) and powerlyra [distributed_hybrid_ingress.hpp](https://github.com/Tjcug/powerlyra/blob/master/src/graphlab/graph/ingress/distributed_hybrid_ingress.hpp) code, in the preprocessing phase, they can get the graph, so the graph topology information can be used.

I want to make use of graph topology information, but I don't know how to add a new function in spark to get the graph data, then give every edge a new `PartitionID`.

Comment: I know a solution is to add a new function in `org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.GraphImpl` and override `partitionBy` function. So, I can get graph data and do not affect other codes. When spark users code graph function,  they can choose the function to partition graph data. But the solution has a disadvantage that we do not implement PartitionStrategy, and it will make the spark code orderless.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach:

- Collect the minimal necessary information from your graph
- Instanciate a `PartitionStrategy` that captures this information

---

As a dummy example, here is a code snippet that partitions `graph` with the following rule: *if the destination is also a source in the graph, then it is assigned to the partition 0, else it is assigned to the partition 1*

```scala
val graph: Graph[_, _] = [...]

graph.partitionBy(
  new PartitionStrategy {
    // select distinct sources only
    val capturedGraphData: Set[Long] = graph
      .edges
      .map(e => e.srcId)
      .distinct()
      .collect()
      .toSet

    override def getPartition(src: VertexId, dst: VertexId, numParts: PartitionID): PartitionID = {
      if(capturedGraphData.contains(dst)) 0
      else 1
    }
  }
)
```

*Note about scalability*: **the memory of driver and executors will be in pain if the use case requires a `capturedGraphData` whose size is too big**, this is why it's important to only select the minimal necessary information from the graph, because it will be collected on driver and broadcasted to every executors.

Comment: this is a completely unscalable solution

Comment: Indeed you are right @AaronZolnai-Lucas, the memory of driver and executors will be in pain if the use case requires a `capturedGraphData` that is huge. I edit to add the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:(java)

```
PartitionStrategy newPS = new PartitionStrategy() {
    @Override
    public int getPartition(long src, long dst, int numParts) {
        //      val mixingPrime: VertexId = 1125899906842597L
        //      (math.abs(src * mixingPrime) % numParts).toInt
        Long mixingPrime = 1125899906842597L;
        return (int) Math.abs(src * mixingPrime) % numParts;
    }
};
graph.partitionBy(newPS);
```